# Accessibility: Pressing "space" on checkbox is not registered correctly by screen reader

Tags: checkbox, vuejs2, vuetify.js, accessibility

We are working on upgrading our app to vue 3, but in the meantime, one of our users has problems with their screen reader which we have to fix within vue 2.

**Problem:** Given a vuetify checkbox, when you press space, the screen reader doesn't notice that the checkbox has been unchecked.

Here is a small code pen: https://codepen.io/jkarczm/pen/LYbYmxz?editors=1010

If you try it without a screen reader, pressing with the mouse or the space - it all looks good, but the screen reader won't pick up that the checkbox changed when you press space (it does pick up when you use the mouse). Screen readers tested and affected: Orca, JAWS, NVDA.

**Analysis so far:**

In that code pen, if you use the developer tools, you can go to the input element for the checkbox and remove the "role: 'checkbox'" property from the HTML. This will result in the underlying input element to be rendered also next to the icon which replaces the natural rendering. Now, if you use mouse clicks, the two checkboxes change accordingly, while if you use the space key, the native checkbox DOES NOT change its value.

I believe that the html here is actually not good: The checkbox should just have a `type: "checkbox"` property, all the rest is unnecessary. It seems that most modern versions of screen readers just ignore the other properties such as `aria-checked` and read out the value of the input and that this is CORRECT behaviour - they didn't do that in the past though, which is why the problem is biting us now.

However, that doesn't tell me why the "native" checkbox doesn't pick up the change - to me it seems that the signals are propagated to the same functions and result in the same changes in JavaScript apart from the value of the input element.

**Question:**
Does anyone have an idea or pointers as to how I could fix it? Vuetify 3 behaves correctly in that regard, but there were a lot of changes so I can't quite put a finger on where the relevant change is coming from.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the fact that `aria-checked` is added to a native checkbox, [which is discouraged in ARIA](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#h-note-10):  Due to the strong native semantics of HTML's native checkbox, authors are advised against using aria-checked on an input type=checkbox. […]

Comment: @Andy I agree that it shouldn't be there - in the newer version of the library I want to move to, they also removed it. But even if I remove it (in the code pen in the html for instance), the problem remains that the native "input" doesn't get updated. I am at a loss as to why that could be the case.

Comment: Notice that if you test it with jaws, the label of the checkbox is "true" when it's checked, but "null" when it is visually unchecked but remains checked for Jaws. Small idea: aria-checked value must be true/false, but checked attribute must be totally absent when unchecked.

Comment: I added `getElementsByTagName("input")` and then printed the value of "checked" to the console log, `console.log(x[1].checked);`. (I added a native checkbox before the vue one so the vue checkbox was the 2nd element in the array from getElementsByTagName). When I use a **mouse** to click on the vue checkbox, the checked status changes. When I use **SPACE**, it does not. (Which matches the visuals of the native check not changing when you remove `role=checkbox` as suggest in the OP.)  This sounds like there's some other vue js code running that is overwriting or resetting the `checked` property

Comment: For info, the problem is still there with Jaws 2024, which has been released last week.

Comment: FYI it works for me with NVDA+Chrome and Edge+Narrator. I've seen misbehavior like this when elements are mistakenly listening for specific keypresses (e.g. ENTER) instead of click events (try sending a synthetic click event to the element to rule this out).